# Python marshmallow cycle issues with Nested subclass

Tags: python, marshmallow

I have 3 marshmallow Schemas with Nested fields that form a dependency cycle/triangle. If I use the boilerplate from [two-way nesting](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/nesting.html#two-way-nesting), I seem to have no problem.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
class A(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    b = fields.Nested('B')

class B(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    c = fields.Nested('C')

class C(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    a = fields.Nested('A')
```

However, I have my own, thin subclass of fields.Nested that looks something like the following:

```
from marshmallow import fields
class NestedRelationship(fields.Nested):

    def __init__(self, nested,
                 include_data=True,
                 **kwargs):

        super(NestedRelationship, self).__init__(nested, **kwargs)

        self.schema.is_relationship = True
        self.schema.include_relationship_data = include_data
```

and I change each Schema to use NestedRelationship instead of the native `Nested` type, I get:

```
marshmallow.exceptions.RegistryError: Class with name 'B' was not found. You may need to import the class.
```

NestedRelationship is a relatively thin subclass and I am surprised at the difference in behavior. Am I doing something wrong here? Am I not calling super appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your extra code that accesses `self.schema`. When you define `A.b` field, it tries to resolve it, but it wasn't defined yet. On the other hand `marshmallow.fields.Nested` does not try to resolve schema on construction time and thus does not have this problem.